# Is there anything while using fill-extrusion in mapbox-gl-js

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I am trying to create a polygon in `mapbox-gl-js` using ***react***. I am using `react-map-gl` as a wrapper for react of mapbox-gl-js.

I have taken example from here https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-extrusion-floorplan/
and everything is live  on https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-wind-l0mtw?file=/src/App.js

Polygon is not displaying in the map.

Comment: Sorry, what is the question? Is it not working correctly?

Comment: @szczocik yes, you can't see polygon in the map.

Comment: Did you try the alternative library? https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl

Comment: I tried but, that didn't fit for my use case. @szczocik can you please tell my why this is not showing polygon on map/